# java Map to XML through XSD

Tags: java, xml, dictionary, xsd

First. Sorry for bad english.
I want to make some "common" transformation of Map  to XML according to given XSD in that way:

- key of the Map will be equal to tag name in XML
- tag names in XML will not be duplicated in different nodes (levels)
- value in Map can contain for example List of Map that represent repeatable tags in the node
- created xml have to accord an xsd.
- etc.

So I am looking for a competent way to realize that.
Is there anybody who worked with similar tasks and can help me?
Any advise will appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Example.

```
Map:  
"fname" : "Asdf"   
"lname" : "Fdsa"
"cars"  : "car" {"car1", "car2", "car3"}

XML:    
<fname>Asdf</fname>
<lname>Fdsa</lname>
<cars>
  <car>car1</car>
  <car>car2</car>
  <car>car3</car>
</cars>
```

Comment: Could you write down an example of XML you want to use? This will help to understand your requirements exactly.

Comment: added a simple example. Created XML files will become as datasouces for some Web Service (_service). _service will take the template name and XML datasource and return document. Each template has own Schema. How could I implement those requirenments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need one single root element. This is the requirement of XML syntax.
Now you can use JAXB. Define you class Data:

```
@XmlType
public class Data {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private Collection<String> cars;

    // getters
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "cars")
    @XmlElement(name = "car")
    public String getCars() {
        return cars;
    }


    // setters.....
}
```

Now your can create instance of this class instance, call all setters to fill the data and then call:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.yourpackage");
Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(data, System.out);
```

And you will see your data serialized as XML on STDOUT.

To parse XML back say:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.panpwr.api.model.deployment");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
Data data = (Data)unmarshaller.unmarshal(in); // in is the input stream for XML
// now your instance of data is populated from XML
```

Comment: Thank you for response! But what if I have several templates of document which uses own similar schemas with different node names, tree depth?.. And for every new template i want just to create XSD and populate Map with apprpriate attributes and my method will convet it to XML...

Comment: You can either create several annotated data classes for each schema or use XML based mapping instead. I personally prefer classes with annotations. But in past I used XML based mapping with Digester.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex! I will try to do as you suggest!